# joomla 3.1 blankpage after login

Tags: php, joomla

When I login to the backend of my website, Joomla redirects me to a blank page with only a password Textbox in it. 
When I insert the password in it nothing happens.

It has been several months since my last login to this website backend, the website itself works fine now, and other users can edit the website from the frontend as well.

My login username and password are correct (I changed the password from the database, MySQL, again but its the same)

My joomla is hosted on Aruba.it. The joomla verion is 3.1. The PHP version is 5.3.1. www.alif.it is the URL of the site

I have tried giving Super User access to another normal user from database (phpMyAdmin) but its the same.

I have changed the `error_reporting` `"default"` to `"development"` and it gave me:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in iceshortcode.php

So I check the lines and i deleted the & sign before two parameters, and now I don't receive any other errors

Does anyone have any idea how can I access the backend again?

Comment: Given that there have been a number of serious security issues since the release of Joomla 3.1, you need to update immediately. You should also talk to your host about updating PHP to a secure version of 5.3 at least.